# Keep alive service even if app got kill , without use of (Foreground service) is that possible? if so then how

Tags: dynamic

In my app, I use one service that should be run even app got killed. Even though I **don't want to use Foreground service that will include notification** that I don't want to include.

I want to run that service to get current time of device every second. If I use simple service and if app got killed. I don't get time every second.. Its not dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep a Service alive indefinitely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219657/how-do-i-keep-a-service-alive-indefinitely)

Comment: Above link you mentioned, It can be done by  Foreground Service but I don't want to include notification. Is there any other way to be done? @zombie

Comment: also that was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/q/10962418/6689101

Comment: please do some search before asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to startForeground() without showing notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962418/how-to-startforeground-without-showing-notification)